# Add touch events to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, angularjs

I am developing an application that collects data by drawing on the map different shapes.

I am usinf LeafletJS and ionic framework, when I test the application on the computer browser it works fine, but when I install it, run it on android device, everything is ok except the drawing controls, they dont work, I guess touch events are not supported by leaflet.draw, I am new to this world and I have no idea on what should be done to make the controls work on touchscreen device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ionic touch-event-to-mouse-event hacks conflict with Leaflet's touch-event-to-mouse-event hacks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675208/ionic-angular-leaflet-directive-zoom-in-out-buttons-do-not-work

Comment: thanks a lot. `data-tap-disabled="true"` should be added to the map container:

`<ion-content data-tap-disabled="true">
    <leaflet height="480px"></leaflet>
</ion-content>`